# What cheat codes can you get in Shower With Your Dad Simulator?

Tags: shower-with-dad-simulator

There appears to be a code entry screen, but how do you discover codes to enter in, and what do these codes do?

Comment: i like your taste in games.

Comment: If you think yourself capable of digging through the executable, and simply have not been bothered to, yet, I suggest you look there. I also suggest you try easy fixes you are aware of before posting questions about it, as this shows unsatisfactory research effort on your behalf.

Comment: @Timelord64 I actually don't even own the game, I bought it for someone else and watched him play it. Even if I had it, this is not the first thing I try and I generally forget that it's possible to do so. Generally, I google around (which I did).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are currently no cheats released for this game.

Comment: Will there be any? Do you have any links to show that the dev plans to release some? Is there any more information you can add here?

Comment: @Seiyria, OP might be better listing a source to confirm, but "dev plans" are discouraged. We do not cover unreleased content or developer intent on this website.

Comment: @Timelord64 yes, that's true, but anything would be better than "there isn't anything (yet)" to be honest.

Comment: @Timelord64 while there is nothing anywhere else, one thing I have done in the past was go dig through an executable to find stuff (for some of my Towerfall answers, that's what I did). Generally, stuff like this is pretty easy to find, especially in a game this small. I just haven't looked personally yet.

Answer (score -2):

if you type in rainday the dads get a rainbow skin

Comment: How'd you find this?

Comment: This is not correct. There is only space for 6 characters.